# Gmail Sign In page - Unable to scroll down till the end

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to automate the gmail sign up page.Once I enter all the mandatory details like user name, pass, DOB, email etc and click on Next Step button, I got a pop up message which needs to scroll down till the end and then Accept button will be enabled.
Below is the code which i am using and its scrolling em down but not enough down so that the "I Accept" button is enabled. I tried below code also to double click but its not scrolling till the end

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.id("tos-scroll-bu‌​tton"))).doubleClick‌​().build().perform()‌​;
```

Here is code//

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='FirstName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='LastName']")).sendKeys("Krishna");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='GmailAddress']")).sendKeys("Krishna.Krishna1154");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Passwd']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PasswdAgain']")).sendKeys("04Mar1989@");
    //Input the month
    List<WebElement> month_dropdown = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthMonth']/div"));
    //iterate the list and get the expected month
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    for (WebElement month_ele:month_dropdown){
    String expected_month = month_ele.getAttribute("innerHTML");
    // Break the loop if match found
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    if(expected_month.equalsIgnoreCase("August")){
        month_ele.click();
        break;
    }
    driver.findElement(By.id("BirthMonth")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(":3")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthDay']")).sendKeys("14");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='BirthYear']")).sendKeys("1988");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id(":e")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryPhoneNumber']")).sendKeys("XXXXXXXX");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='RecoveryEmailAddress']")).sendKeys("XXX@gmail.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("submitbutton")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000L);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tos-scroll-button']/div/img")).click();
```

Comment: I cannot begin to fathom how this doesn't violate Google's terms of service.

Comment: Is there some reason your aren't use the google mail api? I don't think you probably need to test the google site.

Comment: This is just for my practice and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Try scrolling down until Accept button is in view :

```
WebElement element =driver.findElement(by);
        JavascriptExecutor jse =(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```